# KDE - Attach window as tab by default

Tags: arch-linux, kde

I have a 'console' windows that shows the logs of one of my applications, and I really would like to have it always attached to my main window when it starts up. Is there a way to do this?

- Latest version of KDE, running Arch Linux

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently running KDE on Mageia 3 but stumbled on your post in search of the same answer. I have eventually discovered that I can change the special Window settings so that my window will "**Autogroup with identical**" every time.

In your case I'm assuming that the logs console is considered "identical" to the core application. If not, then there are other attributes to chose from, such as "*Autogroup in foreground*" and "*Autogroup by ID*".  Does this help?

Comment: They don't count as identical applications apparently. Where do I get the Window ID for "Autogroup with ID"